# How to get GPG public key sizes?

Tags: gpg

I'm trying to get my GPG configuration back to a sane size. I've just converted pubring.gpg to pubring.kbx using [migrate-pubring-from-classic-gpg](http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gnupg2/gnupg2_2.2.13-2.debian.tar.xz), but despite only containing a few dozen public keys those files are both almost 30 MB. Please correct me if I'm wrong about the normal size of keys, but I suspect this might be because of [certificate spamming](https://gist.github.com/rjhansen/67ab921ffb4084c865b3618d6955275f). So I'm trying to figure out which keys are causing this massive file size (and reducing any GPG-related commands to mush), if that is even meaningful outside of the keys' bit size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On-disk key sizes are related to the number of signatures, so one way to find out which keys to investigate is to run something like

```
gpg2 --with-colons --list-keys --with-sig-list |
awk -F: 'function dump(key, uid, sigs) {
           if (key && uid) {
             printf "%s: %d (%s)\n", key, sigs, uid
           }
         }
         /^pub/ { dump(key, uid, sigs); key = $5; sigs = 0 }
         /^uid/ { dump(key, uid, sigs); uid = $10; sigs = 0 }
         /^sig/ { sigs++ }
         END { dump(key, uid, sigs) }' |
sort -n -k2,2
```

(This mis-counts slightly since subkey signatures are included, but the error isn’t significant.)

Non-spammed keys shouldn’t show more than a few thousand signatures; the largest key in my (cleaned up) keyring is Werner Koch’s 0xF2AD85AC1E42B367, which shows 4,773 `sig` entries and occupies less than one megabyte.

To see a key’s size in your keyring, run

```
gpg2 --export ${keyid} | wc -c
```

Comment: Uh-oh, that was the [Tor Browser Developers signing key](https://github.com/micahflee/torbrowser-launcher/issues/400)